# Trouble with loop and storing data in variables

Tags: java, loops, variables, storing-data

The program I am trying to finish needs to read in three numbers from the user and then store them in the variables `num1`, `num2` and `num3` so that they can be used in steps 2 and 3.  The problem I am having is that when the program loops through after the user inputs their numbers and tries to move on to step 2 or 3, it says must complete step 1 first.

This is my code as of right now:

```
    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int num1;
        int num2;
        int num3;
        int input;

        do {
            boolean opt1Done = false;
            System.out.println("Select your next step");
            System.out.println("1: Enter three numbers between 1 and 100.");
            System.out.println("2: Order your number in ascending order");
            System.out.println("3: Determine if the three inputs form a triangle");
            System.out.println("4: Exit");

            int answer = console.nextInt();
            num1 = console.nextInt();
            num2 = console.nextInt();
            num3 = console.nextInt();
            input = console.nextInt();

            if (answer == 1) {
                //do whatever for option 1
                System.out.println("Enter a value for num1 between 1 and 100.");
                System.out.println("Enter a value for num2 between 1 and 100.");
                System.out.println("Enter a value for num3 between 1 and 100.");

                opt1Done = true;
            } else if (answer == 2) {
                if (opt1Done) {
                    //...... do whatever to order the numbers
                    int[] arraynum;
                    arraynum = new int[3];

                    arraynum[0] = num1;
                    arraynum[1] = num2;
                    arraynum[2] = num3;

                    Arrays.sort(arraynum);

                    int i;

                    for (i = 0; i < arraynum.length; i++) {
                        System.out.println("num:" + arraynum[i]);
                    }

                } else {
                    System.out.println("you must complete Step 1 before Step 2");
                }
            } else if (answer == 3) {
                if (opt1Done) {
                    //... do whatever to determine if triangle or not
                    if (num1 + num2 > num3 && num1 + num3 > num2 && num2 + num3 > num1) {
                        System.out.print("TRIANGLE");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print("NO TRIANGLE");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("you must complete Step 1 before Step 3");
                }
                if (answer == 4) {
                    System.exit(0);

                }
            }
        } while (input != 4);
    }
}
```

Do I need to add another loop or change the one already have?

Comment: seems like its homework. is it?

Comment: its for a project for a programming class yea @MuhammadSuleman

Comment: you broke the code again! Watch out when you edit your question ;)

Comment: `opt1Done` is being set to false after every iteration, Move `boolean opt1Done = false;` before  you begin do ..while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the boolean declaration opt1Done and the numbers outside the loop and read input after every user prompt.

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadChar {

    public ReadChar() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 0;
        int num3 = 0;
        boolean opt1Done = false;

        while (true) {

            System.out.println("Select your next step");
            System.out.println("1: Enter three numbers between 1 and 100.");
            System.out.println("2: Order your number in ascending order");
            System.out
                    .println("3: Determine if the three inputs form a triangle");
            System.out.println("4: Exit");

            int answer = console.nextInt();

            if (answer == 1) {
                // do whatever for option 1
                System.out.println("Enter a value for num1 between 1 and 100.");
                num1 = console.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Enter a value for num2 between 1 and 100.");
                num2 = console.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter a value for num3 between 1 and 100.");
                num3 = console.nextInt();

                opt1Done = true;
            } else if (answer == 2) {
                if (opt1Done) {
                    // ...... do whatever to order the numbers
                    int[] arraynum;
                    arraynum = new int[3];

                    arraynum[0] = num1;
                    arraynum[1] = num2;
                    arraynum[2] = num3;

                    Arrays.sort(arraynum);

                    int i;

                    for (i = 0; i < arraynum.length; i++) {
                        System.out.println("num:" + arraynum[i]);
                    }

                } else {
                    System.out
                            .println("you must complete Step 1 before Step 2");
                }
            } else if (answer == 3) {
                if (opt1Done) {
                    // ... do whatever to determine if triangle or not
                    if (num1 + num2 > num3 && num1 + num3 > num2
                            && num2 + num3 > num1) {
                        System.out.print("TRIANGLE");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print("NO TRIANGLE");
                    }

                } else {
                    System.out
                            .println("you must complete Step 1 before Step 3");
                }

            }
            if (answer == 4) {
                System.exit(0);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't loop over the instructions. Every time you have a step completed, the program then ends and the next time you run it, nothing you've done before is saved.

You need an outer loop to iterate over commands:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;

    boolean opt1Done = false;

    while (true) {

        System.out.println("Select your next step");
        System.out.println("1: Enter three numbers between 1 and 100.");
        System.out.println("2: Order your number in ascending order");
        System.out.println("3: Determine if the three inputs form a triangle");
        System.out.println("4: Exit");

        //rest of your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you must loop until the user choose the option 4. I don't see any loops that encompass the options asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

you are putting condition in wrong place.
as i am thinking first check answer from user then take those 3 numbers inside first condition as

```
int answer = console.nextInt();
    if (answer == 1) {
        //do whatever for option 1
        System.out.println("Enter a value for num1 between 1 and 100.");
        num1 = console.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter a value for num2 between 1 and 100.");
        num2 = console.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter a value for num3 between 1 and 100.");
        num3 = console.nextInt();
        opt1Done = true;
   }
```

and move this line outside of loop

```
 boolean opt1Done = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

- Introduced a while loop and opt1True should outside of the loop
- check for is answer 4 is inside answer 3. So moved that in else if to be same level with other answer checks

  ```
  static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          int num1 = 0;
          int num2 = 0;
          int num3 = 0;
          boolean opt1Done = false;
          while(true) {
          System.out.println("Select your next step");
          System.out.println("1: Enter three numbers between 1 and 100.");
          System.out.println("2: Order your number in ascending order");
          System.out.println("3: Determine if the three inputs form a triangle");
          System.out.println("4: Exit");

          int answer = console.nextInt();
          if (answer == 1) {
              // do whatever for option 1
              System.out.println("Enter a value for num1 between 1 and 100.");
              num1 = console.nextInt();

              System.out.println("Enter a value for num2 between 1 and 100.");
              num2 = console.nextInt();

              System.out.println("Enter a value for num3 between 1 and 100.");
              num3 = console.nextInt();

              opt1Done = true;
          } else if (answer == 2) {
              if (opt1Done) {
                  // ...... do whatever to order the numbers
                  int[] arraynum;
                  arraynum = new int[3];

                  arraynum[0] = num1;
                  arraynum[1] = num2;
                  arraynum[2] = num3;

                  Arrays.sort(arraynum);

                  int i;

                  for (i = 0; i < arraynum.length; i++) {
                      System.out.println("num:" + arraynum[i]);
                  }

              } else {
                  System.out.println("you must complete Step 1 before Step 2");
              }
          } else if (answer == 3) {
              if (opt1Done) {
                  // ... do whatever to determine if triangle or not
                  if (num1 + num2 > num3 && num1 + num3 > num2
                          && num2 + num3 > num1) {
                      System.out.print("TRIANGLE");
                  } else {
                      System.out.print("NO TRIANGLE");
                  }
              } else {
                  System.out.println("you must complete Step 1 before Step 3");
              }

          } else if (answer == 4) {
              System.exit(0);

          }

          }

      }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

All you had to do was add a while loop to your logic and reorder it.

```
    boolean opt1Done = false;
    int num1, num2, num3;
  while(answer != 4){


  System.out.println("Select your next step");
    System.out.println("1: Enter three numbers between 1 and 100.");
    System.out.println("2: Order your number in ascending order");
    System.out.println("3: Determine if the three inputs form a triangle");
    System.out.println("4: Exit");

    int answer = console.nextInt();


    if (answer == 1) {
        //do whatever for option 1
        System.out.println("Enter a value for num1 between 1 and 100.");
        num1 = console.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter a value for num2 between 1 and 100.");
        num2 = console.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter a value for num3 between 1 and 100.");
        num3 = console.nextInt();
    opt1Done = true;
  }

                                    ...


       if (answer == 4) {
                    System.exit(0);

                }
            }
         }
     }
```

Your problem was every time you were looping you were re-declaring and setting the boolean variable to false. Plus your console.nextInts() were in the wrong spot. Also do while is not necessary in this case because the starting value of answer is null and therefore is not equal to four.